# Java client does not form socket with remote TCP server Android app

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-virtual-device

I am able to use a TCP client to send text to a TCP server when my host is local host, but I cannot send text from client to server when client and server are on different hosts or computers on my network because the socket cannot be created. Connection is refused.

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

here is my client working with local host `127.0.0.1`, no connection is refused, data is transmitted

```
String host = "127.0.0.1";
//String host = "10.9.2.121";
int port = 5000;

String sentenceToServer = "hello server";
System.out.println("initializing socket");

Socket clientSocket = new Socket(host, port);

System.out.println("socket initialized");
System.out.println("getting output stream to server");
DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
System.out.println("found output stream to server");
System.out.println("getting input stream from server");
BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
System.out.println("found input stream from server");
System.out.println("writing sentence to server");
outToServer.writeBytes(sentenceToServer+"\n" );
System.out.println("sentence written");
System.out.println("waiting for sentence response from server");
String serverResponse = inFromServer.readLine();
System.out.println("serverResponse = "+serverResponse);
System.out.println("socket closed");
clientSocket.close();
```

and here is my server also running on local host `127.0.0.1`

```
try
{

 String clientSentence;
 welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6000);
 welcomeSocket.setReuseAddress(true);

 while ( true )
 {
    Log.d("TAG", "looking for socket");
    Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
    Log.d("TAG", "socket accepted");
    Log.d("TAG", "getting input stream");
    BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
    Log.d("TAG", "input stream found");
    Log.d("TAG", "getting output stream");
    DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
    Log.d("TAG", "output stream found");
    Log.d("TAG", "reading input stream");
    clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
    Log.d("TAG", "input stream read");
    Log.d("TAG", "input = " + clientSentence);
    Log.d("TAG", "writing output back to client");
    clientSentence = "hello client";
    outToClient.writeBytes(clientSentence + "\n");
    Log.d("TAG", "output written back to client");
 }
}
catch ( IOException e )
{
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but if the server is running on another machine `10.9.2.121` and not `127.0.0.1` where client is running, socket is not created.

Also note that the server is running in an Android app, and port has been forward with telnt

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

and to confirm Android app is listening on port 6000, when I redirect with telnet

```
redir add tcp:5000:6000
hello world
```

I see Android TCP server receives text from telnet on local host, it just can't form socket connection with remote client, but seems at least to have port forwarding configured correctly.

Comment: Try without the redirection. There is no reason telnet connection works and not client socket.

Comment: @HichemBOUSSETTA client socket also works when local, but remote client socket will not work, not a matter of socket just "not working"

Comment: I meant remote socket vs remote telnet. If remote telnet works then client socket must work too.

Comment: @HichemBOUSSETTA I tried to remote telnet, but could not get a connection .. I did instead of `telnet localhost 5000` I did `telnet 10.9.2.2.121 5000`, is that right?

Comment: `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` only can be use if the server and client is run at the same device. Is both devices in the same LAN and `10.9.2.121` is local ip? What is the other device ip? Try ping the `10.9.2.121` from the other device and see whether it is reachable.

Comment: @the_prole ok so remote telnet doesn't work. As Joey said, try first to get ip addresses of both devices to make sure they are in the same network and try ping them

Comment: I had to port forward https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55604467/can-i-port-forward-from-one-interface-port-to-another-interface-port